# Excluding specific schema (or permit specific schema) in galera cluster 3 nodes master-master

Tags: galera

I have 3 dedicated servers connected in a private LAN.

Each one uses Plesk, a tool that (should) help people to manage domains and other server settings. It uses a scheme called **psa** for storing server configuration. Since I want to use those 3 DBs as `Galera Cluster node` (master-master), I wish to know if I can exclude specific schema from the cluster. So all servers can continue to work with Plesk without affecting the schema XXX that I want to synchronize with the 3 nodes and vice versa. I've heard about the directive `replicate-do-db` but I wish to know if it's the right way to achieve that.

Comment: I answer at my same question: Plesk is very intrusive and configuration affect also system tables and so on. I will proceed now creating a secondary isolated mariadb instance dedicate only for the db i want to syncronize. I've tried both adding:
binlog-ignore-db=psa
binlog-ignore-db=roundcube and all the other plesk scheme with no luck. 
Neither binlog-do-db=XXX excluded that plesk tables from the cluster.
Since i'm losing lot of time, i will post here the final solution because i think it can be useful for other people